# Express Request Param Id - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: typescript, express

How can i pass a type to a id request param? It seems that the types of Express put the params of the request as any.

The code where i need to access the id of the request:

```
  const repository: Repository = { 
    ...repositories[request.params.id],
    url,
    title,
    techs
  }

  repositories[request.params.id] = repository;
```

Comment: Maybe i can create a variable with that id and then declare its type as number but i would to know if there's a way to declare the type of an array index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request params by default will be of type string. Even if you cast them to `any` to `number` here, at runtime it will still be a string.

If you want to change the type to number you'll have to use something like `parseInt(request.params.id)`.